# How to create a statically linked extension for sqlite?

Tags: c, sqlite

[sqlite3_auto_extension](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/auto_extension.html) looks like a good way to register a statically linked extension. But I don't understand the callback declaration:

```
void (*xEntryPoint)(void);
```

Shouldn't the callback be like sqlite3_extension_init?

```
int sqlite3_extension_init(
  sqlite3 *db,
  char **pzErrMsg,
  const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm puzzled too why the callback is declared like that.
sqllite calls it like:

```
xInit(db, &zErrmsg, &sqlite3Apis);
```

So you should have e.g.

```
int my_extension(sqlite3 *db, char **pzErrMsg, const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi)
{
  //register stuff
  return 0; //ok
}

...
sqlite3_auto_extension((void*)my_extension);
```

Comment: Probably for ABI compatibility reasons.

Comment: The casting is described in the book [_Using SQLite: Small. Fast. Reliable. Choose Any Three_, section "Building and Integrating Static Extensions"](https://books.google.de/books?id=v5OYlkt6uKYC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=statically+link+sqlite+extension&source=bl&ots=hdY2jnYPNH&sig=ACfU3U0cw6rHvwCTF6ByAepBRLhSM9kJcA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuxdeW8proAhVGQhUIHTeWD8wQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=statically%20link%20sqlite%20extension&f=false). It does not explain the historical reason (ABI compatibility is a good suggestion), but describes it as "odd".